# How to get the element of data attribute value using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Consider the following, how do get the last element of a particular data attribute value?

```
      <tr data-log="sectionA"><td>Log Information</td></tr>
      <tr data-log="sectionA"><td>Log Information</td></tr>
      <tr data-log="sectionA"><td>Log Information</td></tr>
      <tr data-log="sectionA"><td>Log Information</td></tr> <--- I need this last element of sectionA
      <tr data-log="sectionB"><td>Log Information</td></tr>
      <tr data-log="sectionB"><td>Log Information</td></tr>
      <tr data-log="sectionB"><td>Log Information</td></tr>
      <tr data-log="sectionB"><td>Log Information</td></tr>
```

I'm not sure what to try.. thanks for any ideas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
$('[data-log="sectionA"]:last')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U9HQH/